# Dependencies are not satisfied for libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, kde

```
 ~/Dropbox/Abhishek  apt list --upgradeable
Listing... Done
libxkbcommon-x11-0/xenial 0.7.0-1+16.04+build2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.5.0-1ubuntu2]
libxkbcommon0/xenial 0.7.0-1+16.04+build2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.5.0-1ubuntu2]
 ~/Dropbox/Abhishek  sudo apt upgrade                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Entering ResolveByKeep 10%
  Dependencies are not satisfied for libxkbcommon-x11-0 [ amd64 ] < 0.5.0-1ubuntu2 -> 0.7.0-1+16.04+build2 > ( libs )
Keeping package libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Operating System Information:
Ubuntu 16.04 (KDE neon 5.8.5)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Solved it just now with synaptic package  manager. Unfortunately i wasn't really paying attention so I'm not entirely sure what I did. But here we go: You need to find  libxkbcommon in there and you should have 3 packages installed. I think i marked i386 for removal and the rest for upgrade. Got an error at first but second time worked. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using aptitude

`sudo apt install aptitude`

aptitude gives you a couple of options to solve your Dependencies problems.
run the following command to upgrade.

`sudo aptitude upgrade`

and read carefully the given option about what packages it is about to remove or upgrade to solve the dependencies problems before giving confirmation to execute.